# Script downloads data files but I can't stop the script

Tags: python, loops, curl, terminate

### Description of code

My script below works fine.  It basically just finds all the data files that I'm interested in from a given website, checks to see if they are already on my computer (and skips them if they are), and lastly downloads them using cURL on to my computer.

### The problem

The problem I'm having is sometimes there are 400+ very large files and I can't download them all at the same time.  I'll push Ctrl-C but it seems to cancel the cURL download not the script so I end up needing to cancel all the downloads one by one.  Is there a way around this?  Maybe somehow making a key command that will let me stop at the end of the current download?

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
import urllib2
import re
import timeit

filenames = []
savedir = "/Users/someguy/Documents/Research/VLF_Hissler/Data/"

#connect to a URL
website = urllib2.urlopen("http://somewebsite")

#read html code
html = website.read()

#use re.findall to get all the data files
filenames = re.findall('SP.*?\.mat', html)

#The following chunk of code checks to see if the files are already downloaded and deletes them from the download queue if they are.
count = 0
countpass = 0
for files in os.listdir(savedir):
   if files.endswith(".mat"):
      try:
         filenames.remove(files)
         count += 1
      except ValueError:
         countpass += 1

print "counted number of removes", count
print "counted number of failed removes", countpass
print "number files less removed:", len(filenames)

#saves the file names into an array of html link
links=len(filenames)*[0]

for j in range(len(filenames)):
   links[j] = 'http://somewebsite.edu/public_web_junk/southpole/2014/'+filenames[j]

for i in range(len(links)):
   os.system("curl -o "+ filenames[i] + " " + str(links[i]))

print "links downloaded:",len(links)
```

Comment: Read in the contents into a var and write the contents to a file. You dont have to use curl in this case. Also, to parse HTML you shouldn't use regex. Another tip, use threading to make downloads simultaneous.

Comment: Oh thats a good idea, and kinda obvious writing to a file would be good.  I'm not sure how I would download the files with out cURL?  And why are regex bad for parseing html?  I'll look into threading as well.

Comment: You would open up the url `links[j] = 'http://somewebsite.edu/public_web_junk/southpole/2014/'+filenames[j]`, read its contents `data = str(urlConn.readlines())` and then open a file for writing `f = open(filenames[j], 'w') f.write(data)`

Answer (score 0):

You could always check the file size using curl before downloading it:

```
import subprocess, sys

def get_file_size(url):
    """
    Gets the file size of a URL using curl.

    @param url: The URL to obtain information about.

    @return: The file size, as an integer, in bytes.
    """

    # Get the file size in bytes
    p = subprocess.Popen(('curl', '-sI', url), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    for s in p.stdout.readlines():
        if 'Content-Length' in s:
            file_size = int(s.strip().split()[-1])
    return file_size

# Your configuration parameters
url      = ... # URL that you want to download
max_size = ... # Max file size in bytes

# Now you can do a simple check to see if the file size is too big
if get_file_size(url) > max_size:
    sys.exit()

# Or you could do something more advanced
bytes = get_file_size(url)
if bytes > max_size:
    s = raw_input('File is {0} bytes. Do you wish to download? '
        '(yes, no) '.format(bytes))
    if s.lower() == 'yes':
        # Add download code here....
    else:
        sys.exit()
```